# Webpack migration 3 -> 4: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin'

Tags: migration, webpack-3, commonschunkplugin, webpack-4

I'm trying to migrate from webpack 3 to webpack 4.

The issue I have is with CommonsChunkPlugin, when I try to run webpack (`npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config config/webpack.dev.js`), I have the following error:

```
module.js:529
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/antoinepissot/DEV/Reports/config/webpack.common.js:17:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
```

**What is causing this issue ?**

I looked at the [change log on webpack github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases) and found that CommonsChunkPlugin has been removed

But when I look at the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/), I can find CommonsChunkPlugin for version 4.1.1

My gut feeling is telling me that `CommonsChunkPlugin` is deprecated and we should use `optimization.splitChunks`.

Did anyone experienced the issue and found a good tutorial to migrate from version 3 to 4 ?

Comment: `CommonsChunkPlugin` was removed -> `optimization.splitChunks`, `optimization.runtimeChunk`. You can find detailed information [how to migrate chunk plugin here](https://gist.github.com/sokra/1522d586b8e5c0f5072d7565c2bee693)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack 4 migration CommonsChunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017682/webpack-4-migration-commonschunks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vardius pointed out in his comment, CommonsChunkPlugin was removed.

In webpack 4, this behaviour is done using ["optimization"](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/) field at the root of webpack config.

For instance, this is how my webpack.config.js looks like now:

```
module.exports = function () {
   return {
    resolve: ...
    module: ...
    plugins: ...
    optimization: {

       namedModules: true, // old NamedModulesPlugin()
       splitChunks: {      // old CommonsChunkPlugin
          chunks: "all"
       },
       runtimeChunk: true,
       concatenateModules: true // old ModuleConcatenationPlugin
    }
}
```