# In webpack 4, how to only splitChunks on one entry?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks

I have two entries: page1.js, page2.js.

I don't want to extract shared codes between two entries. I only want to extract node_modules used in page2.js.

How do I achieve this in webpack 4? Thanks.

Comment: What does `preload.js` contain? Can you create a reproducable minimal example on git..?

Comment: `preload.js` should be `page1.js`, `index.js` should be `page2.js`. Sorry about the confusing names. What `page1.js` contains shouldn't affect anything here.

Comment: Webpack 4 now by default does optimizations automatically. It analyzes your dependency graph and creates optimal bundles (output), based on the following conditions:

New chunk can be shared OR modules are from the node_modules folder
New chunk would be bigger than 30kb (before min+gz)
Maximum number of parallel request when loading chunks on demand <= 5
Maximum number of parallel request at initial page load <= 3

Question: Now why would you want to do, what you want to do? :-)

Comment: For the longer version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213048/2581562

Comment: But if you still want to do it the way you ask for, just setup a little exampel repo on github and I will take a look.

Comment: https://github.com/blackChef/webpack_multiple_entry_test/tree/master

Comment: We have to clear some things upfront. Currently you have page1 and page 2 as entry-points,  both have a dependency on `lodash` in your sample repo. With the current config it extracts `lodash` which resides under `node_modules` into a speparate output file named `page1_vendor.build`. This file contains the shared dep `lodash`.
And you want to extract `lodash` for page1 into a separate file (current config), but for page2 you want `lodash` to be part of `page2`?
Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible without hooking into the build process using a custom plugin. But still don't get what is the main-goal doing it like this?  Because WP4 outputs optimized bundles already, which can be tweaked using the `splitChunks` section.

Answer (score 0):

In Webpack 4, you will have to have **two** `webpack.config.js`, one for each entry, i.e. you will have to build them separately.

In Webpack 5, you can use `chunks()` function of SplitChunksPlugin, [see the docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkschunks):

> Alternatively, you may provide a function for more control. The return value will indicate whether to include each chunk.

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks(chunk) {
        // exclude `my-excluded-chunk`
        return chunk.name !== 'my-excluded-chunk';
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Important is also to define the chunk name at the specific entrypoint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73871637/webpack-chunks-split-for-website-and-widget-based-on-entrypoint/73881742#73881742

Answer (score -2):

From the official docs, having multiple entries will create separate dependency graphs for each entry.

```js
const config = {
  entry: {
    pageOne: './src/page1.js',
    pageTwo: './src/page2.js',

  },
  output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')   
  }
};
```

Reference: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application

Comment: The OP asks about Webpack 4, `CommonsChunkPlugin` is not there.

Answer (score -4):

You can use the following config:

```
splitChunks {
  vendor: {
    name: 'vendor',
    chunks: 'all',
    test: /node_modules/
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't because it is extracting `node_modules` from both pages.