# Error: webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.splitChunks instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, commonschunkplugin, webpack-cli

I am getting this error

> Error: `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` has been removed, please use `config.optimization.splitChunks` instead.

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  filename: DEBUG ? 'bundle.js' : 'bundle.min.js',
  name: "vendor"
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error states, the plugin is deprecated since webpack 4

You should remove it and use a different plugin.

There are plenty of posts where you can find how to do this but here is an example: [Webpack 4 migration CommonsChunkPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017682/webpack-4-migration-commonschunkplugin)